# Как установить View Controller как стартовый View

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, iphone

Привет!
Разрабатываю без storyboard, поэтому не знаю, как созданный ViewController установить стартовым. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В AppDelegate.m

```
 self.window.rootViewController = [[TCDemoViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: Немного более полный вариант:

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        self.window.rootViewController = [[TCDemoViewController alloc] init];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
    }